# Is Happy in Edens Zero the same as Happy of Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail, edens-zero

In episode 3 of *Edens Zero*, behind Rebecca, I saw Natsu and Lucy with Fairy Tail tattoos. However, Happy was not with them, Happy is now with Rebecca and Shiki.

[image]

Is everything about Happy the same as *Fairy Tail* series' Happy?

Answer (score 2):

*Edens Zero*'s Happy is not the same as *Fairy Tail*'s Happy. The two Happys have different and conflicting origins. *Fairy Tail*'s Happy is a member of the Exceed race of talking winged cats which came from an alternate reality from the main universe of Earth Land called Edolas, meanwhile *Edens Zero*'s Happy was a non-winged talking cat from the planet Excede in the Sakura cosmos who was run over by a drunk driver and had his consciousness loaded into a robot body.

You could propose some kind of theory that both Happys are somehow the same whether that involve alternate realities, reincarnation, or other handwaving, but the real answer is probably simpler, it's simply a cameo.

Both *Fairy Tail* and *Edens Zero* were created by the same mangaka, Hiro Mashima and he is pretty well known for carrying characters across his 3 main series' *Rave Master*, *Fairy Tail*, and *Edens Zero* (E.G. RM's [Sieghart Caesar](https://ravemaster.fandom.com/wiki/Sieghart_Caeser), FT's [Jellal Fernandes](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Jellal_Fernandes) and EZ's [Justice](https://edenszero.fandom.com/wiki/Justice) are all blue-haired dudes with facial tattoos who wield a spell called Grand Chariot). Characters from his previous works cameo frequently in his subsequent works, [here's a Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fairytail/comments/evfr31/cameos_from_the_cast_of_rave_master_hiro_mashimas/) listing *Rave Master* cameos in the first few hundred *Fairy Tail* chapters, you'll notice it tends to be one to a few characters cameoing at a time as opposed to the entire cast and they take turns.

*Fairy Tail* Happy might somehow be *Edens Zero* Happy, or he might just not be in this cameo and show up next time, is the nature of cameos.

Comment: your answer is good and I know this much, but I will still look what else they will reveal in later story of eden's zero, in the recent episode they again showed lucy and natsu but not happy. I also saw gray but without fairy tail tatto we cannot say he is gray.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli I can't say its impossible Eden's Zero will explicitly confirm or deny the two Happy's are the same but it seems tangential to the story, so far in the EZ manga despite the cameos no one has explicitly acknowledged FT because it would make no sense in-universe. Fairy Tail likewise never officially acknowledged Rave Master despite the cameos, the closest we get is Fairy Tail X Rave which is a crossover where it is revealed the Plue from RM is distinct from FT's Plue but its unclear if this one-shot is canon since if crossovers are canon Goku is BFFs with Luffy (Cross Epoch)

Comment: maybe they create a cross episode of Eden's zero and fairy tale where 2 happy meet each other, or maybe they reveal something else, creating a special episode is possible.